# the measure of the set of x where f(x)= ∞ is zero

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,\boldsymbol M, \mu)$ be a measure space where the measure $\mu$ is positive.

Let $f : X \to \mathbb R^+$ be a measurable function such that $\int f \text d \mu < \infty$. Let $N = \{x \in X: f(x) = \infty\}$.

Why $\mu(N) = 0$?

My attempt: It seems to make sense that the measure of the set of $x$ where $f(x)= \infty$ is zero.

But I am stuck with a rigorous proof. Can someone help me with that. I am rather stuck.

Comment: I would say start with the definition of $\int_X f d\mu$, how is this integral defined?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for any $k\in \mathbb N$, $$\{ f = \infty \} \subset \{f \ge k \}.$$  Consider the integral $$ \int_{\{f \ge k \}} f \,d\mu. $$ Write a lower bound and an upper bound for it, and compare the two. Hope this helps!

BTW, I'm writing $\{P\}$ as short hand for the set $\{x \in X \colon P(x) \}$.